# Cannot find module 'react' in IE only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp

I am building my React project using gulp. Build is successful. And its working fine for chrome & mozilla but **not for IE ONLY**. In my code I do import like this ***import React from 'react';***
Below console i am getting.
 **"Cannot find module 'react'"**
*Please let me know if further details required*

```
gulp.task('build', function() {
    return browserify({
            entries: './server/es5/bcv-app.jsx',
            extensions: ['.jsx'],
            debug: true
        }).transform('browserify-css', {global: true})
        .external(dependencies)
        .transform('babelify', {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
            plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties']
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('server/public/dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add babel-polyfill in your entries section.
You can install through following command.

> npm install --save babel-polyfill

And then require or import it in your file like below.

> require("babel-polyfill");
>
> import "babel-polyfill";

```
    gulp.task('build', function() {
    return browserify({
            entries: ['babel-polyfill','./server/es5/bcv-app.jsx'],
            extensions: ['.jsx'],
            debug: true
        }).transform('browserify-css', {global: true})
        .external(dependencies)
        .transform('babelify', {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
            plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties']
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('server/public/dist'));
});
```

Comment: getting this Error: Cannot find module '/vagrant/babel-polyfill' from '/vagrant'

Comment: I can see babel-polyfill in my nodemodules even though getting above erro

Comment: Thanks Krina I got it working by making few changes in the library code manually and now its working for IE. I have found the root cause i.e. arrow functions & Destructuring assignment is not working so need to find some polyfill for them. Let me know if you have any idea i am using gulp.